# Outlook 2010 Randomly Adds Optional Meeting Recipients

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I am running Outlook 2010 32-bit on Windows XP SP3.

I have noticed that when I send a meeting invite to one or more Active Directory Contacts, Outlook appears to randomly duplicate the contacts as optional attendees.

For example, if I add a contact named "Joe Bloggs (IT Department)" and send the request, when I reopen the request I will also see "Joe Bloggs " listed as an optional attendee.

If I try to remove the duplicate contact, that person receives a cancellation notice despite still being included as a required attendee on the meeting.

Has anyone encountered this and does anyone have a solution?

Thanks